Cockroft-Walton multiplier reactance
I'm newbie in electronics. Already made my first multiplier and it works but like to improve the design.
I did math and calculated reactance (source of formula) and I got 86000 Ohms.
If LTSpice estimated output voltage as 90kV, how I should go step forward to calculate final result (estimated output voltage decreased by reactance)?
FYI - in my case this is data for reactance calculation:

n (number of stages) - 3 (6 diodes and 6 capacitors)
f (frequency) - 55kHz
Epk (input voltage) - 15kV
C (capacitance) - 1000pF 50kV
Iload - 0,01A


If you have the load and source impedance in the LTspice simulation that should already account for voltage drop due to load
